# Check if property was included in POST body

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

For the following posts from the client

```
$http.post('my/url', {}); // 1
$http.post('my/url', {value: null}); // 2
```

I'd like to determine on the server side if the property was not passed (1), or explicitly passed as null (2). Can I ask this of Jersey, somehow?

```
@POST
@Path('my/url')
public Response myPost(Body body) {
  body.getValue(); // null in both cases
  isDefined(body, 'value');
}

class Body { private String value; /*get,set omitted*/ }
```

How do I implement the `isDefined` method? Does Jersey have some kind of tooling for that? I would accept any kind of syntax here. It should return false for (1) and true for (2). Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky... Here are two solutions that came up to my mind:

### Solution 1

You could have an attribute like `valueDefined`. Its state is set to `true` if the `setValue(String)` method is invoked. This solutions works with Jackson.

```java
public class Body { 

    private String value; 
    private boolean valueDefined;

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.valueDefined = true;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public boolean isValueDefined() {
        return valueDefined;
    }
}
```

The resource method would be like:

```
@POST
@Path('my/url')
public Response myPost(Body body) {
    boolean valueDefined = body.isValueDefined();
    ...
}
```

### Solution 2

Use a `Map<String, Object>` instead of `Body` and check if the key `value` is present:

```java
@POST
@Path('my/url')
public Response myPost(Map<String, Object> map) {
    boolean valueDefined = map.containsKey("value");
    ...
}
```